# Android games leaderboard broken while testing

Tags: android, testing, google-play-games, leaderboard

I have successfully integrated the Google Games API in my app, and now I can see my leaderboard and achievements as described [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/leaderboards#before_you_begin) and [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/achievements#unlocking_achievements) respectively.

However, when trying to submit a score using this code:

```
Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(mGoogleApiClient, getString(R.string.play_console_leaderboard_id), 100);
```

for some reason the leaderboard stops appearing. Actually it starts loading, and then directly disappears. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684053/google-play-game-has-stopped-after-update-score-to-leaderboard?rq=1) seems to describe the same issue, however there is no solution posted.

I know that it has to do with the submitScore because when I create a new leaderboard, I can successfully open it and see the message that no one has reported any score. Then again, if I try to submit a score, the leaderboard again breaks.

Any hints / suggestions on that?
Thanks.

**EDIT:** I am starting to believe that for some reason it may have to do with the tamper protection from the Play Console. Although even when I tried to disable it, the problem still persists..

**EDIT2:** Do I have to publish my game so I can test the leaderboards? I know that it sounds weird.

Comment: Hey you might want to check this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25369560/android-score-not-being-submitted-to-a-leaderboard). It might provide you the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer noogui, but it seems that the issue is somewhere else; I am already passing the leaderboard id using the getString().

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem, did you ever find a solution? Looking into what you've posted below (debug certificates) at the moment. I tried [this]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25507922/google-play-games-services-achievement-activity-closing-immediately) which prevents the crash, but it returns as soon as I submit another score to the leaderboard.

Comment: Regarding the SHA1 fingerprint mentioned below, I could not find anything on this. So eventually, I just uploaded a beta version to the Play Console and tried the scoreboard, which was working.

Comment: oh man, i have the same issue i think. I dont know what the hell is going on. I can view leaderboard by reconnecting but when i try to submit any score I get STATUS_CLIENT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED error. I checked that if i make a new service using new pakage name, eveything works fine. Did u manage to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Even these days when I still try to see my leaderboard while in debug mode, I also get the STATUS_CLIENT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED, however if I try the same code be generating an actual release apk and install it, everything works. So I would suggest, try your code in the released apk.

Answer (score 3):

After testing with the submitScoreImmediate, I saw that I got STATUS_CLIENT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35904481/google-play-games-services-realtime-multiplayer-status-client-reconnect-requ) post, I figured that I had to create another OAUTH client id, using my debug.keystore.

And this was true; when I created a release certificate-signed APK and tried it, everything worked.

Now, Google mentions [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting#check_your_metadata_tags) the following:

> Note: If you are debugging your game using your debug certificate but
>   have configured games services using your release certificate, you
>   should add a second linked app using the same package name and your
>   debug certificate's SHA1 fingerprint. This will allow you to sign in
>   to the application whether it's signed with the debug or release
>   certificates.

However, if I try to link a 2nd app with the same package, I CANNOT apply another SHA1 fingerprint, since the Approval button does not appear, and thus cannot provide my debug key.

Is there any help on this?

Comment: I managed to workaround this by removing all api credentials through https://console.developers.google.com/apis and re linking both apps afterwards, one with release certificate and the other with debug certificate.